# Não consigo enviar valores para WebService .NET

Tags: java, android, web-service

Este é um webService de conversão simples de dólar:

```
public class Callsoap {

    String resultado;
    String erro = null;

public String Call (String ip, String porta, float n){

    String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://"+ip+":"+porta+"/webservice/WebService.asmx?wsdl";
    String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    String OPERATION_NAME = "Conversor";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Conversor";

    int Timeout = 60000;
    HttpTransportSE ht;
    SoapObject request;

    request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    request.addProperty("n",String.valueOf(n));

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);


    ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,SOAP_ADDRESS,Timeout);


    try{
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");

        SoapObject resultadoXML = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapPrimitive resultados = (SoapPrimitive) resultadoXML.getProperty("ConversorResult");
        resultado = resultados.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        return erro = e.toString();
    }
    request = null;
    ht = null;
    envelope = null;

    return resultado;
}

private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    return envelope;
}
}
```

Comment: Dê mais informações sobre o problema. Este código não é C#.

Comment: Este é um app Android e envio uma variavel para multiplicar dentro do webservice e voltar um número. Mas sempre retorna 0

Comment: Então isto não é C#, certo?

Comment: Sim certo! é Android tentando conectar em um Webservice .net

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/99376/edit) a sua pergunta, faça as alterações necessárias às `tags` e adicione também mais informações para construir melhor a sua pergunta. Eu quando formatei o código da pergunta adicionei também a tag `C#` consoante a informação do título, pois eu não percebo nada de ambas as linguagens, mas você deve editá-la e adicionar/remover as tags consoante o seu contexto de encaixe.

Comment: O WebsSrvice tá rodando em debug ou você publicou ele?

Comment: Publiquei no IIS local

Answer (score 0):

1. Tente trocar a linha `envelope.dotNet = false;` por `envelope.dotNet = true;`
2. Verifique se o tipo de dados gerado no webService está correto para uma conversão correta na hora de trazer os dados de retorno;

Eu utilizo o KSoap2 para trabalhar com WebServices .NET, o que você pode verificar também é sobre a necessidade de registrar no objeto `SoapSerializationEnvelope` o tipo de dados que esta utilizando para o retorno, se o tipo de dados for decimal no .NET provavelmente vc vai ter que criar uma classe de `Marshal`, como exposto abaixo:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.Marshal;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

public class MarshalDecimal implements Marshal {

    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String stringValue = parser.nextText();
        return new java.math.BigDecimal(stringValue);
    }

    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object instance) throws IOException {
        writer.text(instance.toString());
    }

    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) {
        cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "decimal", java.math.BigDecimal.class, this);
    }
}
```

E no método `getSoapSerializationEnvelope()` você vai ter de adicionar a seguinte instrução:

```
new MarshalDecimal().register(envelope);
```

Comment: Troquei para testar true por false... Mas MSM assim não funciona!

Comment: A função devolve string... E recebe strings mas sempre retorna zero não está chegando ate o wbeservice os valores

Comment: @SilasPSilva, eu sugiro que você procure uma ferramenta como o WSDL2KSoap2 para converter o seu webservice para Android e baseado no código gerado, voce pode encontrar a origem do seu problema.